# Using nifi, how can I insert JSON objects into a Postgres jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, etl, apache-nifi, jsonb

Currently, my nifi process is as follows:

ListS3 -> RouteOnAttribute -> RouteOnAttribute -> FetchS3Object -> ConvertRecord  -> PutDatabaseRecord

I list CSV files in the s3 bucket and then route on two different attribute processors to select the files I want to put in a Postgres database. I then fetch the CSV files from s3. Then, I use a ConvertRecord processor to convert my CSV files into lines of json objects like the following:

{"ideez": "1", "name": "John Doe", "age": "30", "city": "New York"}
{"ideez": "2", "name": "Jane Smith", "age": "25", "city": "Los Angeles"}
...
[image]

The reason I want to do this is because there are many CSV files with a similar titles (that I route to use the correct ones) and have mostly similar columns. But there are a number of files that have different column names. Changes day to day. So inserting them as a json object into a jsonb column in Postgres would work best for me.

Here is how my JsonRecordSetWriter is setup as well as my PutDatabaseRecord:

[image]
[image]

Here are some of the errors I'm receiving:

- failed to put records to database for
  flowfile[filename=this/that/then/this/filename] routing to
  failure:java.sql.SQLDataexception: none of the fields in the record
  map to the columns defined by the public.test_table table NORMALIZED
  COLUMNS: ID,JSONCONTENT
- putdatabaserecord[id=uuid] record does not have a value for required
  column ‘json_content’

If I try and encapsulate each of the lines with "json_content":
{"json_content": {"ideez": "1", "name": "John Doe", "age": "30", "city": "New York"}},
{"json_content": {"ideez": "2", "name": "Jane Smith", "age": "25", "city": "Los Angeles"}},
...
I get the following error:
“ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token “MapRecord” is invalid. Where: JSONdata, line 1: MapRecord… unnamed portal parameter $1=‘…’

Has anyone had any luck doing a similar process? Perhaps, there is a better process I should be pursuing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're really close! But the issue is that your content:

```
{"json_content": {"ideez": "1", "name": "John Doe", "age": "30", "city": "New York"}},
{"json_content": {"ideez": "2", "name": "Jane Smith", "age": "25", "city": "Los Angeles"}}
```

has the json content as an actual json object, which NiFi interprets as a Record. Hence the error about MapRecord. You'll need to "stringify" this field. I think there are some solutions that I can look into, in order to make stringifying the JSON more convenient. But for now, you could do so using raw string manipulation. I'd use a ReplaceText processor just before your PutDatabaseRecord, and configure it this way:

```
Replacement Strategy = Regex Replace
Search Value = (^.*$)
Replacement Value = {"json_content": "${'$1':escapeJson():replace('\\', '\\\\')}"}
Character Set = UTF-8
Maximum Buffer Size = 1 MB
Evaluation Mode = Line-by-Line
Line-by-Line Evaluation Mode = All
```

That should handle converting it into a string and properly escaping it.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for your help Mark.